# xamarin forms deserialize json

Tags: json, xamarin

my app consumes data from rest api and gets json

code in my app:

```
var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://192.168.0.101:8000/api/list");
```

JSON

```
"count": 10,
"next": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/list?page=2",
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "name": "lorem ipsum1",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/2.jpg",
        "description": "lorem ipsum5"
    },
    {
        "name": "lorem2",
        "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/pictures/1.jpg",
        "description": "lorem ipsum4"
    }
```

and i have a class i want to use to deserialize "count"

```
public class Count
{
    public int count { get; set; }
}
```

my question is: can i deserialize only "count": 10 ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show exactly what you get. That is not a valid JSON response. Did you try your class for deserialization? Did you run into any issues?

Comment: i can deserialize "results" into observable collection like this: var obj = JObject.Parse(JsonString); var menu = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dishes>>(obj["results"].ToString()); But i dont know how to deserialize  only "count". and i want to use class Count for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. You just have to build a model class with that single property `Count` and deserialize with Newtonsoft.Json.

```
public class Dto
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I made a .NET fiddle for you:

- https://dotnetfiddle.net/VeG6ta

---

Note that I had to fix your sample JSON:

- the whole json is missing an opening an closing brace "{" & "}"
- the results array had no closing bracket "]"
- the stuff with `.Replace("'", "\"");` is just required because I had to use `'` instead of `"` in the C# string. You don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want a single value, you can just parse the data into a `JObject`

```
var data = JObject.Parse(json); 
        
Console.WriteLine(data["count"]);
```